# Randomly lose the connection to router

Tags: router, network-monitoring, windows-sbs-2011, networking

I have been suffering with in this problem for a really long time and I'm running out of ideas.

We have VMWare (Intel model server, Intel storage - Windows storage op. system, ). In the virtual enviroment we have one SBS2011 Standard, and two terminal servers.

Users report internet fault few times a day (random times..). Every time when they call me, I only see the Terminal Server (most users work on this server) has lost connection with router. (ie: cannot ping gateway - router).

In this time I can access all the other servers and internal LAN IP's from the terminal server but can't reach router. I use ConnectionMonitor to monitoring when this occurs, but I can't find two same timestamp. I try to monitor this on SBS also, but I see the problem there too.

But the SBS and the Terminal Server connectivity problem does not occur at the same time.

Please ask any information, any screenshot, whatever you need, but please try to help me resolve this 'coz i'm pullin' out my hair..

thank you

**I checked:**

- no task run in this time
- no disk, memory, cpu, network related issue in vcenter
- no event warning or error related of this issue (i think)
- check events for service control. No service runnin' (stopping or starting) at time when connection lost.

Comment: Get on the router (serial console is handy for this) and see what the router sees while you're having trouble.

Comment: i did not see anything on router log. And when TS lost connection SBS not, or vica versa..